# How to use different assets if local or live

Tags: theme-development

When building locally I want to use an unminified version of my JS. On the live site, I want to use the compiled and uglified version.

In my theme, what's the best way to output the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has constants that can be defined in the wp-config.php. [Have a read here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Something like this might help

```
//setup the production names for the files
$js_file = 'scripts.min.js';
$css_file = 'styles-compressed.css';

//check for WP_DEBUG constant status
if( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG ) {

    //check for SCRIPT_DEBUG constant status
    if( defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) {
        $js_file = 'scripts.js';
        $css_file = 'styles-development.css';
    }
}

//load the files
wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin_scripts', $basepath . '/js/' . $js_file  );
wp_enqueue_style( 'plugin_styles', $basepath . '/css/' . $css_file  );
```